# Понижение/Изменение версии pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Как понизить версию pip? Например, у меня `20.3`, а нужна `20.2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это можно сделать средствами `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==20.2
```

Comment: Ага. И при этом флаг upgrade. Забавнo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Почти так как и в прошлом ответе:

```
pip install pip==19.2.3 # Около == не должно быть пробелов!
```

Таким же образом можно устанавливать и другие пакеты:

```
pip install pillow==3.1.5 # Версия для примера.
```